# Showing a build number or version on Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, versioning

I have a Silverlight app that I hand off to the IT people you are supposed to publish it.  This does not always happen correctly, they might forget, put in the wrong loc, or get the wrong version.

So I want to add something to the app itself to easily tell the latest version.  This is for SL 3 and 4 so context menu probably not an option.  I don't think the users would want a splash screen so that also probably not a choice.

Has anyone done this?  Is there a clean, unobtrusive way of doing this?

If you have done this do you just use the assembly version or do use some custom value?

thanks

Comment: can you just look at the assembly file on the server and see what version it is? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to check the assembly version of a running application:

```
string GetAssemblyVersion()
{
    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(Application.Current.GetType().Assembly.FullName);

    if (assemblyName == null)
    {
         return string.Empty;
    }

    Version v = assemblyName.Version;

    if (v == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return v.ToString();
}
```